# What is the format/style of a math paper published in a peer-reviewed journal?

Tags: math-history, publishing

I'm writing a math history essay but it was assigned to "conform to the style of mathematics paper published in a peer-reviewed journal". I don't know what this means. I don't know much about this so I can't find an example.

What would the font be? The spacing? The citation?

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: [Guidelines of the AMS](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf). On page 4 the talk about the font. The $\LaTeX$ document type [`amsart`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsart?lang=en) should give you a general look according to it.

Comment: Do you not have access, hola, to a library that subscribes to one or more peer-reviewed journals?

Comment: Many journals, for example all of the Elsevier journals today only require that you submit your paper in LaTeX and the journal typesetters will take care of proper formatting according to the journal's specification. You don't even need to format the references according to the journal's style, the typesetters will take care of that too. This is, of course, the least you can expect from Elsevier who earn billions of dollars per year.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a dummy text math paper here, formatted with $\LaTeX$. 
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-of-elsevier-article-template-with-dummy-text/qfscmwntknmq

I suspect your instructor only wants you to mimic the general style and organization, not necessarily match fonts. You should probably ask about that.

If you're ambitious you can learn a little $\LaTeX$ and let it format your paper. (The overleaf site offering this sample can manage that in the cloud for you.)